# Como esconder uma senha no C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Quero esconder a minha senha.

O que eu quero que que aconteça é que enquanto eu digito o " * " seja mostrado no lugar dos caracteres, o problema é que isso acontece só quando eu clico no botão "Logar".

Sim, eu sei que isso acontece por que os comandos estão dentro do bloco do evento do botão, mas como posso tirá-los de lá?

Tentei fazer fora do evento mas não consigo usar a caixa de texto, o que posso fazer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É só definir a propriedade [**`PasswordChar`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar(v=vs.110).aspx) do TextBox, não precisa de nenhum evento extra.

```
txtSenha.PasswordChar = '*';
```

Answer (score 4):

Os campos `TextBox` possuem uma propriedade chamada [`UseSystemPasswordChar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.usesystempasswordchar(v=vs.110).aspx), altere ela para `true`.